# How to clean this data

Tags: python, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

From this:

```
+------+------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| code | type |           name           | final_component |
+------+------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| C001 | ACT  | Exhaust Blower Drive     |                 |
| C001 | AL   |                          |                 |
| C001 | AL   |                          |                 |
| C001 | SET  | Exhaust Blower Drive     |                 |
| C001 | AL   |                          |                 |
| C001 | AL   |                          |                 |
| C001 | AL   |                          |                 |
| C002 | ACT  | Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump  |                 |
| C002 | SET  | Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump  |                 |
| C003 | ACT  | Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump  |                 |
| C003 | SET  | Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump  |                 |
| C004 | ACT  | Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump  |                 |
| C004 | SET  | Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump  |                 |
+------+------+--------------------------+-----------------+
```

Expected:

```
+------+------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| code | type |           name           |     final_component      |
+------+------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| C001 | ACT  | Exhaust Blower Drive     | Exhaust Blower Drive     |
| C001 | AL   |                          | Exhaust Blower Drive     |
| C001 | AL   |                          | Exhaust Blower Drive     |
| C001 | SET  | Exhaust Blower Drive     | Exhaust Blower Drive     |
| C001 | AL   |                          | Exhaust Blower Drive     |
| C001 | AL   |                          | Exhaust Blower Drive     |
| C001 | AL   |                          | Exhaust Blower Drive     |
| C002 | ACT  | Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump  | Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump  |
| C002 | SET  | Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump  | Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump  |
| C003 | ACT  | Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump  | Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump  |
| C003 | SET  | Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump  | Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump  |
| C004 | ACT  | Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump  | Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump  |
| C004 | SET  | Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump  | Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump  |
+------+------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

i have to copy the name value whose type is 'SET' to final_component for all the same code
like for C001, name for type 'SET' is Exhaust Blower Drive
i have to copy that to final_component for all C001

```
for ind in dataframe.index:         
    if dataframe['final_component'][ind]!=None:
        temp = dataframe['final_component'][ind]
        temp_code = dataframe['code'][ind]
    i = ind
    while dataframe['code'][i] == temp_code:
        dataframe['final_component'][ind] = temp
        i+=1
```

i could come up with this
but it gets stuck in the while loop

Comment: It will be good if you write down expected output very clearly

Comment: @anuragal, please have a look now, lemme know if the question is clear..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution 1: when data is grouped in order

If your data in `'name'` field already has Null values, then you can do something simple as ffill(). Pandas dataframe.ffill() function is used to fill the missing value in the dataframe. ‘ffill’ stands for ‘forward fill’ and will propagate last valid observation forward. In this case, it does not take into consideration the values in `code`. If you want to consider that as well, then look at solution 2.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = {'code':['C001']*7+['C002']*2+['C003']*2+['C004']*2,
     'typ':['ACT','AL','AL','SET','AL','AL','AL','ACT','SET','ACT','SET','ACT','SET'],
     'name':['Exhaust Blower Drive',None,None,'Exhaust Blower Drive',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,
             'Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump','Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump',
             'Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump','Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump',
             'Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump','Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump']}

df = pd.DataFrame(a)

#copy all the values  from name to final_component' with ffill()
#it will fill the values where data does not exist
#this will work only if you think all values above are part of the same set

df['final_component'] = df['name'].ffill()
```

## Solution 2: when data has to be based on another column value

If you are required to fill based on value in code, you can use the below solution.

You can do a lookup and then update the values. Try something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = {'code':['C001']*7+['C002']*2+['C003']*2+['C004']*2,
     'typ':['ACT','AL','AL','SET','AL','AL','AL','ACT','SET','ACT','SET','ACT','SET'],
     'name':['Exhaust Blower Drive',np.nan,np.nan,'Exhaust Blower Drive',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,
             'Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump','Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump',
             'Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump','Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump',
             'Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump','Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump']}

df = pd.DataFrame(a)

#copy all the values  from name to final_component' including nulls
df['final_component'] = df['name']
#create a sublist of items based on unique values in code
lookup = df[['code', 'final_component']].groupby('code').first()['final_component']
#identify all the null values that need to be replaced
noname=df['final_component'].isnull()
#replace all null values with correct value based on lookup
df['final_component'].loc[noname] = df.loc[noname].apply(lambda x: lookup[x['code']], axis=1)

print(df)
```

The output will look like this:

```
    code  typ                     name          final_component
0   C001  ACT     Exhaust Blower Drive     Exhaust Blower Drive
1   C001   AL                      NaN     Exhaust Blower Drive
2   C001   AL                      NaN     Exhaust Blower Drive
3   C001  SET     Exhaust Blower Drive     Exhaust Blower Drive
4   C001   AL                      NaN     Exhaust Blower Drive
5   C001   AL                      NaN     Exhaust Blower Drive
6   C001   AL                      NaN     Exhaust Blower Drive
7   C002  ACT  Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump  Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump
8   C002  SET  Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump  Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump
9   C003  ACT  Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump  Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump
10  C003  SET  Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump  Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump
11  C004  ACT  Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump  Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump
12  C004  SET  Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump  Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach.  First, re-create the data frame:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''| code | type |           name           | final_component |
| C001 | ACT  | Exhaust Blower Drive     |                 |
| C001 | AL   |                          |                 |
| C001 | AL   |                          |                 |
| C001 | SET  | Exhaust Blower Drive     |                 |
| C001 | AL   |                          |                 |
| C001 | AL   |                          |                 |
| C001 | AL   |                          |                 |
| C002 | ACT  | Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump  |                 |
| C002 | SET  | Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump  |                 |
| C003 | ACT  | Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump  |                 |
| C003 | SET  | Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump  |                 |
| C004 | ACT  | Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump  |                 |
| C004 | SET  | Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump  |                 |
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='|',)
df = df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 5'])
```

Now, remove leading and trailing spaces:

```
# remove leading / trailing spaces
df.columns = [c.strip() for c in df.columns]
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].dtype == object:
        df[col] = df[col].str.strip()
```

And populate `final_component`:

```
# populate 'final component'
df['final_component'] = df['name']
```

Now replace empty strings with `None` and use `ffill()`

```
# find final component that is empty string...
mask = df['final_component'] == ''

# ... and convert to None...
df.loc[mask, 'final_component'] = None

# ...so we can use ffill()
df['final_component'] = df['final_component'].ffill()
print(df)

    code type                     name          final_component
0   C001  ACT     Exhaust Blower Drive     Exhaust Blower Drive
1   C001   AL                              Exhaust Blower Drive
2   C001   AL                              Exhaust Blower Drive
3   C001  SET     Exhaust Blower Drive     Exhaust Blower Drive
4   C001   AL                              Exhaust Blower Drive
5   C001   AL                              Exhaust Blower Drive
6   C001   AL                              Exhaust Blower Drive
7   C002  ACT  Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump  Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump
8   C002  SET  Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump  Spray Pump Motor 1 Pump
9   C003  ACT  Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump  Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump
10  C003  SET  Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump  Spray Pump Motor 2 Pump
11  C004  ACT  Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump  Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump
12  C004  SET  Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump  Spray Pump Motor 3 Pump
```

Comment: Pandas `dataframe.ffill()` function is used to fill the missing value in the dataframe. ‘ffill’ stands for ‘forward fill’ and will propagate last valid observation forward. However it does not take into consideration values in `code`. The OP is looking for forward fill based on value in `code`

Comment: @JoeFerndz, you are correct.  I up-voted your answer, which includes `groupby()` in your Solution 2.